# NOC code for Devops Engineer - 2173 or 2174

Tags: canada, citizenship, express-entry, pr

My designation is Senior Software Engineer, where my roles and responsibilities are as of a devops engineer -- build and release and cloud (AWS)

Please help me chose the best NOC code for Canada PR.

Thanks

Comment: Are you currently employed in Canada? Have you asked your employer which code you should use?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much information about your job responsibilities here. Regardless going with what you have given, **[NOC 2173](http://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=122372&CVD=122376&CPV=2173&CST=01012011&CLV=4&MLV=4) and [NOC 2174](http://noc.esdc.gc.ca/English/noc/Profile.aspx?val=7&val1=2174) both should work**. However NOC 2173 matches more closely.

Also they are both closely related when looking at responsibilities. I would suggest go with NOC 2173.